# Ubuntu 20.04 GSConnect

Tags: android, 20.04

Upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04. Seems to be gsconnect not supported in 20.04, cant find in software store. any other ways to connect android with ubuntu 20.04 desktop?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep?hl=en get this extension for chrome or search name for firefox, click on icon, search for gsconnect. This worked for me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's in the official repositories:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect
```

There is another package which will enable browser support (Firefox/Chromium):

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect-browsers
```

The universe repository needs to be enabled, otherwise `apt` will be unable to locate the packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Answer (score 1):

Over at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/ the following suggestion is given in the comments:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0
```

I tried it on one of my machines and can confirm it works. But it does install a lot, so I'm not yet convinced this is the correct route. I hope the plugin itself gets updated to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried launching GSConnect on Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10, with no result.
The 'gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect' package seems to be completely broken.
However, there is a solution.
Just visit https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/ and install the extension from here. You'll need first to integrate the 'GNOME Shell extension' into your browser, but then all is just a piece of cake.
The new version of GSConnect from the GNOME site works just fine.

Comment: Even when GSConnect is installed, its icon is not seen in the Tray on Ubuntu 20.04. Anyone know how to make its icon appear in the Tray or how to run it?

Comment: Install mtp-tools or gmtp, worked for me. Also note that some USB cables have no data channel, thus you can only charge the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking Settings icon of GSConnect in Gnome Shell Extensions window shows 'Searching for devices' even though KDE Connect app is running on my Android phone. KDE Connect app on my phone doesn't see my Ubuntu box.