# GSConnect not working after upgrading to ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, android

GSConnect is unable to find my android device. I am able to ping my phone from the laptop and vice versa. Also tried solutions suggested here: [Ubuntu 20.04 GSConnect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230155/ubuntu-20-04-gsconnect). Any suggestions are appreciated.

Edit: also tried to add device by IP, which is not working as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the update, the firewall was blocking the port 1716 which is used by GSConnect. Used `sudo ufw allow 1716` command to allow the port, which solved the issue.

To ensure that the port is not being used by any other process, use `lsof -i UDP:1716`. (If the port is being used by GSConnect, the output will have `gjs` as the COMMAND).

Comment: Just wanted to note that I've been frustrated for weeks with GSConnect not showing devices on my laptop and  `sudo ufw allow 1716` immediately resolved this.